# Powerpoint graph unsmoothed in presentation mode

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Graphs of a diagram appear a lot less smooth once the presentation mode starts. The figure below depicts this. The upper is in regular PowerPoint mode (that is when I am editing the file), the lower is in the actual presentation (that is, while in screen-show mode). Can this be fixed? The lower version is really not presentable. In a PDF file it appears smooth, but I really need the PowerPoint function where notes can be displayed on a second screen.

[image: Two screenshots from Powerpoint]

Comment: I don't think I understand what the phrases "regular powerpoint mode" and "the actual presentation" mean. Perhaps if your screen shot was wider it would be more obvious. Could you elaborate on these phrases. For example is one the view you see when you are editing the presentation file, and another is the view when you run it as a slide show? If so, which is which?

Comment: The first one is the view when I'm editing the presentation file, the second (lower one) is the one that appears once I run it as slideshow.

Comment: Try disabling slide show hardware graphics acceleration.  It's in File | Options | Advanced, in the Display section.